# Problem with some WSO2 Default Attributes

Tags: wso2

Does anyone know what these default attributes of wso2 mean:
- Endpoint_ActiveChildren
- Endpoint_ReadyChildren
- Endpoint_TotalChildren

I tried find the answer on wso2 api manager documentation,but it's not enough.

Comment: Where do you have these in APIM?

Comment: where did you find this?

Comment: APIM haven't that info .... The exporter convert wso2 data for I can use it on prometheus and return that 3 attributes. That's the problem !!